# Get previous posted videos using stream details from Wowza Stream Engine Manager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wowza

Is it possible to get the posted videos on Wowza Stream Engine (not a live video) by using the stream details (file name etc...) in iOS? I am able to post the live video by using the Wowza config details but is it possible to get the posted videos on Wowza?

Comment: @orde Is this is possible to get previously posted videos? if possible to get the posted videos(not a live video) Can i get some referral link?

Comment: I've removed the duplicate flag because I'm not sure if it's a dupe or not.  I'm not clear on your question, however.  What do you mean by "posted"?